# How can you specify the order of properties in a javascript object for a MongoDB index in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, indexing

The [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) states:

> For indexes with more than one key (i.e. compound indexes) **the sequence of fields is important.**

But ECMAScript defines an object as follows:

> An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function.

When using `MongoDB` in `node.js` (for example by using [this module](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)), you're using server side javascript, like the example below.

How do you specify a sequence when MongoDB expects an `object` (AKA unordered collection of properties)?

```
collection.ensureIndex({
    date    : -1,
    client  : 1,
    product : 1
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the "unordered" property of JavaScript because they implemented their own version of js for the shell. Try `show dbs` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention Node.js (javascript) as the scripting language.

Comment: The properties may not in practice necessarily be quite as unordered as the ECMA spec dictates that they *may* be ( http://jsfiddle.net/D4zC8/2/ ). In Chrome and IE 10, the key order is consistent there. It wouldn't surprise me too much if a new fresh object literal behaved that way in all the major implementations. It seems pretty crazy to release code relying on that behavior, though. In Chrome, if I delete a property and replace it, the key order changes. In IE10, it doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MongoDB, the order of fields in a document is indeed significant, and all language drivers provide a means of specifying documents that way, even if the underlying programming language does not have such a concept.

The document format that MongoDB uses in its shell is JSON-like but not strict JSON. Among other things, order of fields is always preserved.

In Javascript, the standard defines fields as unordered, so implementations are free to ignore/not preserve the ordering.  But **in practice, all implementations do preserve the ordering. In particular the `V8 engine` preserves the ordering, which is the engine used in `node.js` so it's no problem.**

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is about using `MongoDB` in `Node.js` which is server side javascript. So my worries are not about how Mongo handles it internally, but the javascript part.

Comment: The V8 engine does indeed preserve ordering, although it is defined as unordered in the standard. That is a grey area that currently seems to be handled sufficiently well (because all environments essentially preserve ordering), but may need to be more closely looked at in the future.

Comment: Some testing shows that V8 indeed preserves this order all the time. You should edit your comment into your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I've edited your answer in order to emphasis the actual answer (pending review), and accepted it.

Comment: Given the spec this seems like a dangerous assumption to make for such a widely-used piece of software. Does the API allow you to use an array instead of an object, just to make sure it's safe in the future?

Comment: @download According to [this V8 bug report](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164), the order is maintained for non-numeric names. The node.js driver also allows a syntax of `coll.ensureIndex([[a: 1], [b: -1]], cb)` if you don't want to rely on that.