# Why does Mongoose (MongoDB) reorder my array after saving?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a seeds.js file that contains data like this:

```
var newBus = new Bus({
  am: {
    route: [
      {
        coords: {lat: 35.645329, lng: -84.068154},
        address: "5408 Hutton Ridge Rd"
      }
  }
}
```

and when I call

```
newBus.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(data);
});
```

it stores it as something like this:

```
"am" : {
    "route" : [
        {
            "address" : "5408 Hutton Ridge Rd",
            "coords" : {
                "lng" : -84.068154,
                "lat" : 35.645329
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I just noticed that it changed the order of `lat, lng` to `lng, lat`.  I wouldn't think it would matter, but when I was doing an update to the seed data, the update only worked when I found the array that matched a specific `lng, lat`.  It didn't work when I tried to find a match with `lat, lng`.

So why does MongoDB/Mongoose reorder the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an array, it's an dictionary (object in javascript). This does not store any order. It's said in documentation.

You can read more about it here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf (section 4.3.3)

which says:

> Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered**
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  But obviously MongoDB doesn't store it randomly, and lng, lat is not alphabetical order, so why does it end up ordered this way?

Comment: And I suppose the bigger question is should I depend on it being lng, lat if it will not always be ordered in that way?

Comment: I'm not expert in MongoDB topic, but you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514188/how-can-you-specify-the-order-of-properties-in-a-javascript-object-for-a-mongodb It looks like the author is worried about the same thing as you are